# Fantasy series: elf finds crystal in maze, kills army

Tags: story-identification

I believe in one of the books an elf makes his way through a maze to find a black crystal of some sort. When he leaves the maze there is an army outside waiting for him and he uses it to kill the army.

Also I believe in another book of same series, they are trying to make a sword. They find a blacksmith with an amazing sword already made. He won't sell it, but he says if they get the material he'll make them a new one.

Edit:(All credits to CBredlow for the answer.For a more detailed answer look below.)

Then name of the first book in the series that contains both of my above scenarios in the books is "The First King Of Shannara."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the Shannara series by Terry Brooks, with both parts being from the novel "First King of Shannara". The elf is looking for the black elfstone, and has to use it to save himself and his friends.  The second part is from the same story, since the sword is specially forged (though they pick the blacksmith based off of that beautiful sword) and it requires special metals and forging techniques.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_King_of_Shannara

Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannara

Comment: Was there a black crystal (used to kill an army), a maze and a broken sword?

Comment: @Richard  In the first one, yes, there is a broken sword, there is a black crystal (black elfstone) but I can't remember if it killed an army or not. Also, question for you, did that main character have one arm? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Druid_of_Shannara

Comment: this sounds close but some of the details are off; I don't think there was a maze involved in finding the elfstone, it was in a fortress. Plus, I don't think there were more than one copy of the Sword of Shannara?

Comment: It's been about 12-13 years sense I read the book. >.< Sorry if my details are off, just remember it being good and wanted to know.

Comment: But I'm pretty sure I remember the guy using the stone at a great cost.

Comment: Sounds about right to me, but it's been decades since I've read those books.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield There wasn't more than one copy of the sword of shannara, but the broken sword mentioned would be the Sword of Leah

Comment: The Black Elfstone was brought up in Druid of Shannara, but it wasn't even in the maze that was traversed to find it; someone had already grabbed it and left a trap in its place.  It was also never used against an army (it's nature is anti-magic, so it's only used against a spell around a vanished castle).  I don't even think there's an army in that book at all (Sword, Elfstones, and Heritage have 'em tho).  So I don't think this is it.

Comment: @Radhil I may be off in the story then, but there are some similarities.  I will stand by my opinion that it's at least referring to the Shannara series.

Comment: Well I'm pretty sure when the "elf", or who ever went and retrieved the dark crystal(I believe it was evil or cursed), when he made his way outside the "maze" and there were people waiting to take it. So he used it to kill them, knowing of the horrible consequences to himself for using it, can't remember what the consequences were.

Comment: I'm gonna go ahead and mark this right, I think you could be right and since it's been so long I've forgotten a lot of the details. Thanks For All The Help!!!

Comment: Oh! I am an idiot, so that is both from "First King of Shannara"! I remember the black elfstone being mentioned, and there is an elf there as well who has to use it to save his friends from an army! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_King_of_Shannara

Comment: @Clyde edited my answer to reflect new discoveries.

Comment: @CBredlow - I either never read First King or forgot it completely then.  Apologies; reversed my vote.

Comment: @CBredlow Awesome! Thanks CBredlow, glad to finally have the name of that book.